# how to create hook for send email to profile2 type user

Tags: users

In my project there are two types of user.Using profile2 module i creates 2 profiles.
1) normal user
2) Lawyer

So i have to send promotion email to lawyer after registration.
i created following rule.

1) Event
 - After saving a new profile

2) condition
 - user has roles

a]After selecting they ask for  **Data selector**. i don't know what i select for my lawyer account

b]i select "lawyer" Roles

c]match roles - all)

3) Event
 In event i select send-email

a]email function $to - how i can put current user registration email

b] body is static

c] subject is static

I am really confuse. Can i create hook for send email to lawyer after registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In condition `add data comparison instead of user role` if want to send mail only basis of profile type as below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:

In Action Section 
Select Send Main or Send Html Mail under System and follow as below png file.
[image]

This may help it..

Comment: In action i select send email option, but in "TO"  how i can put current registration user email

Comment: Please help me...

Comment: i have edited the answer please check it i think it will help you...

Comment: Yup,I receive email but they showing error messege "Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists."

Comment: I think you did not configure mail system correctly, that's why it showing this error. it does not related to rule module. Please check the mail system configuration ..

Comment: I disable the SMTP module to take default server setting but nothing happened

Comment: I received email, why they showing me this error.

Comment: did you check the db log why the error is occurring ? please check it.can you please share the error ?  also check if server mail is enabled or not?

Comment: I receive both email and our rules working fine but they showing error message. There is no need of error message.our process is working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22294/discussion-between-swapnil0226-and-bisw).